# Python script to open and write to several terminals using SSH

Tags: python

I have a Jetson AGX with several cameras connected to it. In order to control the cameras from my Windows PC, I have connected to the Jetson with SSH.

In order to start capturing images from several cameras at once, I need multiple terminals open. So far I have this:

```
import os

os.system('start cmd /c "ssh jetson_name@IP_adress"')
os.system('start cmd /c "ssh jetson_name@IP_adress"')
os.system('start cmd /c "ssh jetson_name@IP_adress"')
```

This opens 3 terminals on my windows PC and each one of them establishes a connection to the Jetson. So far so good.

1. After I open a terminal, how do I write to it? It's a bit of a stupid question, but I only know how to open cmd and pass **one** command to it - in this case, the command to ssh to the jetson. After this, I want to pass the command to start streaming.
2. I'd like to start streaming simultaneously from 3 cams. The above process is really slow. So, could I open 3 terminals, like above, and then afterwards pass commands separately to terminal to start streaming?

The command to stream is something like:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=pixelformat=XR24 --stream-mmap --stream-count=1 --stream-to=img.raw
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried subprocess?

```
import subprocess


addresses=['jetson_name@IP_address1','jetson_name@IP_address2','jetson_name@IP_address3']
# Open three terminals and store the Popen objects in a list
terminals = []
for address in addresses:
    cmd = ['ssh', '-t', address]
    terminal = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    terminals.append(terminal)

# Send a command to each terminal
for count,terminal in enumerate(terminals):
    command = f'v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=pixelformat=XR24 --stream-mmap --stream-count=1 --stream-to=img{count}.raw'
    terminal.stdin.write(command.encode())
    terminal.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Hm, I'm getting:   "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Also, another thing, this would try to open /dev/video0 three times, but I need from three different devices: /dev/video0, /dev/video1 and /dev/video2. I didn't put this in my question, sorry. Thanks for your help regardless - Aleks

Comment: Obviously, this will also overwrite the name "img.raw"..